# Entry input lag in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
public decimal CurrencyConversion(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    string url = string.Format(urlPattern, fromCurrency, toCurrency);

    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = wc.DownloadString(url);

        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken token = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        decimal exchangeRate = (decimal)token.SelectToken("rate");
        var result = (amount * exchangeRate);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hello everyone, that's the code I'm using whenever I'm trying to insert new numbers in the entry field there is 1-sec delay until the next number is shown. Any idea how I can fix that? :o

Comment: at a glance, I'd guess the delay is due to the time it takes to make the request and process it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay must be only due to the time it takes to DownloadString and process it. The only thing you could do here is to download the string asynchronously which would reduce the load in your main thread to reduce the delay a bit.

```
public async decimal CurrencyConversion(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    string url = string.Format(urlPattern, fromCurrency, toCurrency);
    var wc = new WebClient();
    var json = await wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);

    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken token = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
    decimal exchangeRate = (decimal)token.SelectToken("rate");
    var result = (amount * exchangeRate);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Finally: If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks :)

Comment: Hey thank you for your replay. I've tried your method but now I'm getting System.Threading.Task.task1[System.decimal] http://prntscr.com/q67rso you can see it here. Do u have any ideas how to solve that now? :D

Comment: The posted answer should just work fine. I have made a few corrections. In case, if you still get an error please send me the stack trace or more details to debug the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

That is the code that worked for me you're getting lag only till the value has been stored in ConcurrentDictionary thereafter everything is smooth.

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, decimal> cachedDownloads =
       new ConcurrentDictionary<string, decimal>();

        public async Task<decimal> CurrencyConversionAsync(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
        {
            string content = "";
            string url = string.Format(urlPattern, fromCurrency, toCurrency);
            Decimal result = 0;
             decimal exchangeRate = 0;
            if (CheckForInternetConnection() == false)
            {
                result = amount * decimal.Parse("1.11");
               return result;
            }

            if (cachedDownloads.TryGetValue(content, out exchangeRate))
            {
                    result = (amount * exchangeRate);
                    return result;

            }
```